Understanding the Behavior of `isLicci(I)` in Macaulay2 for Squarefree Monomial Ideals
I am studying Licci squarefree monomial ideals, where the definition is typically given in the polynomial ring localized at the maximal ideal (Licci ideals can be defined more generally in a regular local ring).
Let $R$ be a regular local ring, and let $I, J$ be proper ideals of $R$. Then $I$ and $J$ are said to be directly linked, denoted by $I \sim J$, if there exists a regular sequence $\mathbf{z} = z_1, \ldots, z_g$ in $I \cap J$ such that:
$$
J = (\mathbf{z}):I \quad \text{and} \quad I = (\mathbf{z}):J.
$$
Moreover, $I$ is said to be linked to $J$ if there exists a sequence of direct links:
$$
I = I_0 \sim I_1 \sim I_2 \sim \cdots \sim I_m = J.
$$
In this case, $I$ is in the linkage class of $J$.
In particular, if one can choose $J$ to be a complete intersection ideal (i.e., an ideal generated by a regular sequence), then $I$ is called Licci.

In Macaulay2, there is a function isLicci to check if an ideal is Licci, but the computation is performed in the polynomial ring, which is not local. What does this function actually check?
For example, consider the ideal:
$$
I = (x_1x_2, x_3x_4, x_5x_6, x_7x_8) \quad \text{in } R = K[x_1, \ldots, x_8],
$$
and let $\mathfrak{m} = (x_1, \ldots, x_8)$.
According to Theorem 3.7, $I_\mathfrak{m}$ (the localization of $I$ at $\mathfrak{m}$) is a Licci ideal. However, when I ask Macaulay2 if $I$ is Licci using isLicci(I), it returns false.
It seems that Macaulay2 checks whether $I$ is Licci only in the polynomial ring without considering the localization at the maximal ideal, which makes the result inconsistent with the theoretical definition in a local setting.
Is this understanding correct? Or is there something about the behavior of the isLicci function in Macaulay2 that I am missing?

Let us try a simple example. Take $R=k[a,b]$ and $I=(a^3,b^3)$. Clearly, $I$ is licci. But the isLicci(I) command says otherwise. (I am not entirely sure why, but the method relies on creating random links, and maybe the base field is small.)
i23 : R=ZZ/101[a,b];
i24 : I=ideal "a3,b3";
o24 :  Ideal of R 
i25 : isLicci(I)
o25 =  false 

Now if you read the documentation here, you will find that using the optional input UseNormalModule => true makes the computations more precise, but slow. Indeed, we see that
i26 : isLicci(I,UseNormalModule=>true)
o26 =  true 

Here is your example:
i32 : R=ZZ/101[a..h];
i33 : I=ideal "ab,cd,ef,gh"
o33 =  ideal(ab,cd,ef,gh) 
o33 :  Ideal of R 
i34 : isLicci(I,UseNormalModule=>true)
o34 =  true 

I hope this helps.

Thank you for your helping! However, I don't have still clear in which sense Macaulay2 checks the Licci property (in the polynomial ring? That is, M2 looks for the regular sequence in the polynomial ring and not in the localization?)

Do you know the reason why they consider localization? In other words, why can't we just require everything to be graded objects? I am seeing this for the first time, so I don't know the subtleties.

These are excellent questions, but unfortunately, I don’t know the exact reasons. It appears that one can work in the graded context—as suggested in https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0708.3369 —but all the papers I have read primarily focus on the local context.
The preference for the local context might be related to implicit reasons found in Corollary 5.13 of the work by Huneke and Ulrich (https://doi.org/10.2307/1971402). Perhaps localization at the maximal ideal ensures certain structural properties.

My guess is that M2 is using homogeneous elements to verify licci property. You can verify this by closely inspecting the codes given here. Obviously, if $I$ is homogeneously licci, then $I_m$ is licci in $R_m$, since you can use the same elements in $R_m$.

I think the codes actually need some updates. For example, if you try to run the example given in Theorem 2.4 of https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0708.3369 over a large finite field, isLicci gives false as output, which is wrong. And it was taking too much time when I tried to work over QQ. Btw, notice that this package is not published in any journals, so it is possible that there are some mistakes.
